# Index on integer and string fields

Tags: mysql, index-tuning, myisam

A table has about 300M records. Each has an unique ID that starts with 13 to 14 digits (with the first digit on the left being either 1 or 2), and is optionally followed by a string of up to 7 ASCII chars. Two examples are `1450123410123` and `21347854123024Asd_uhA`.

Currently, I'm storing this field as a `VARCHAR` with a `PRIMARY KEY`, and am worried about the memory usage of the index. I'm thinking of splitting this field into two columns, a `BIGINT` and a `VARCHAR`. Will the `PRIMARY KEY` created as a combination of these two columns consume less memory?

**Update:** Here are the two possibilities.

Please note that I care about inserts and updates. I will have only one huge select to export the data after a long time.

```
CREATE TABLE without_split (
  id varchar(21) CHARSET=ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  content text NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY id
);

CREATE TABLE with_split (
  id_prefix bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  id_suffix varchar(7) CHARSET=ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  content text NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (id_prefix, id_suffix)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyISAM! Shame.  Switch to InnoDB.

Don't worry about that `PRIMARY KEY`; it is too much hassle to split it up, etc.  But do make sure it is the 'appropriate' character set:

```
VARCHAR(21) CHARACTER SET ascii
```

If it is case sensitive, then add on `COLLATE ascii_bin`.

Yes, there is a memory and disk penalty.  But there are tradeoffs with speed, simplicity, etc.

(If it were 100 characters long, I might give a different answer.)

**Numbers for MyISAM**

In MyISAM, assuming the strings are half length on average:
`PRIMARY KEY(decimal_14_0, varchar_7)` needs 2*(7+(1+3.5)) bytes.
`PRIMARY KEY(varchar_21)` needs 2*(1+(13.5+3.5))

- 2* because PK fields stored with data and with index;
- 7 bytes for `DECIMAL(14,0)`;
- 1=length field for `VARCHAR`;
- 3.5(?)=avg bytes for up-to-7-char suffix;
- 13.5(?) for avg # digits in prefix.

After cancelling out things, the diff is 2*(13.5-7)=13 bytes smaller per row (data+pk) for `DECIMAL+VARCHAR`. 300M*13=4GB.

(InnoDB computation is in Comments.)

Comment: Thanks! This is the configuration I actually have. I'm willing to trade simplicity for memory. Will the split free up some memory?

Comment: InnoDB is 2x-3x more bulky on disk than MyISAM.  InnoDB's secondary keys implicitly include a copy of the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Etc.  If you would like a longer answer, please provide two `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- split, and not split.  I will explain the diffs, and estimate the space diff.  And supply a typical `SELECT`.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: Need more -- MyISAM vs InnoDB?  Any secondary indexes?  Typical SELECT?  And if you are going to squeeze all you can out, use `DECIMAL(14,0)` (7 bytes) instead of `BIGINT` (8 bytes).

Comment: I can switch to InnoDB if that will reduce memory usage. No secondary index. I will have a single `SELECT *` at the end of the process. `DECIMAL(14,0)` is a nice idea actually. I'd love to have it in the final answer.

Comment: If all you are doing is periodically "exporting all the data", then the PK is irrelevant (unless you want it in PK order) and the RAM size is irrelevant (because the process will be I/O-bound.  What's the average row size?

Comment: Please assume that the PK is relevant and focus on answering the precise question that I asked (i.e., is `memory(id_prefix + id_suffix) < memory(id)`). Is it always the case? Or can you come up a counter example situation?

Comment: _Assuming_ MyISAM, the equation is 2*(7+(1+3.5)) versus 2*(1+(13.5+3.5)):  2=(PK fields stored with data and with index); 7 for `DECIMAL`; 1=length field for `VARCHAR`; 3.5(?)=avg for up-to-7-char suffix; 13.5(?) for avg # digits in prefix.  After cancelling out things, the diff is 2*(13.5-7)=13 bytes smaller per row (data+pk) for `DECIMAL`+`VARCHAR`.  300M*13=4GB.

Comment: For InnoDB, the diff is perhaps 1*(13.5-7-1)=5.5; 300M*5.5=1.7GB, but the disk footprint would still be bigger, overall.

Comment: MyISAM can live without a PK; InnoDB cannot.

Comment: Please post the MyISAM comment as an answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!